# can i have a listview and an expandablelistview in the same view

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have several edittexts in my view for taking input for a database query .I'm displaying the query results in a list view below the edittextfields. Because there are 7 edittextfields there is not enough space for the listview. I wanted to put all the edittexts in an expandablelistview.

Problem i'm facing is -only the expandablelistview item is shown -the listview doesnt come up at all --i have @android:id/empty and @android:id/list entries ---but nothing comes up

i can't add the listview into the expandablelistview as that is not allowed + since i need both @android:id/empty and @android:id/list to show query results i need a proper list view.

what are my options --? i could ofcourse display the results in a separate window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could show the xml you have right now it would be great but the ideas behind it needs to be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
Okay so i figured out that for this layout to function correctly you need to set dome weight so that the linearlayout understand what size to give each children. Use:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in the listview and the expandablelistview (1 in both means thay will divide space between them)

Comment: hey thanks, I had it in the above format but when it gets displayed the ListView is not shown-- even when the expandablelistview is not expanded.(there is lot of space below it, maybe i missed something)                                                                        For the time being i stopped using expandablelistview , instead went for  ListView followed by all the edittext fields -- this way the query results are visible.

Comment: I updated my answer, if this helped you in any way please help others and accept my answer as the answer to the question ;) Thanks!